# Enable sharding from C# MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using Mongo 4 with the latest C# driver. My application creates DBs and Collections on the fly and I want to enable sharding. I'm using the following code:

```
if (!ShardingEnabled) return;
var database = collection.Database;
var databaseName = database.DatabaseNamespace.DatabaseName;
var collectionName = collection.CollectionNamespace.CollectionName;
var shardDbScript = $"{{ enableSharding: \"{databaseName}\" }}";
var shardDbResult = database.RunCommand<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>(new MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument() {        
    { "eval",shardDbScript }
});
var adminDb = Client.GetDatabase("admin");
var shardScript = $"{{shardCollection: \"{databaseName}.{collectionName}\"}}";
var commandDoc = new BsonDocumentCommand<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>(new MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument() {
    { "eval",shardScript }
});
var response = adminDb.RunCommand(commandDoc);
```

I get an 'ok' response back from mongo, but my dbs arent sharded.
Output from sh.status()

```js
{  
    "_id" : "uat_Test_0",  
    "primary" : "SynoviaShard2",  
    "partitioned" : false,  
    "version" : { 
        "uuid" : UUID("69576c3b-817c-4853-bb02-ea0a8e9813a4"),  
        "lastMod" : 1 
    }
}
```

How can I enable sharding from within C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. This is how you shard a database and its collections from c#, note, that the sharding key index must already exist:

```
if (!ShardingEnabled) return;
var database = collection.Database;
var adminDb = Client.GetDatabase("admin");
var configDb = Client.GetDatabase("config");
//var dbs = Client.ListDatabaseNames().ToList();
var databaseName = database.DatabaseNamespace.DatabaseName;
var collectionName = collection.CollectionNamespace.CollectionName;
var shardDbResult = adminDb.RunCommand<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>(new MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument() {
    { "enableSharding",$"{databaseName}" }
});
var shardScript = $"{{shardCollection: \"{databaseName}.{collectionName}\"}}";
var commandDict = new Dictionary<string,object>();
commandDict.Add("shardCollection", $"{databaseName}.{collectionName}");
commandDict.Add("key",new Dictionary<string,object>(){{"_id","hashed"}});
var bsonDocument = new MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument(commandDict);
var commandDoc = new BsonDocumentCommand<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>(bsonDocument);
var response = adminDb.RunCommand(commandDoc);
```